# Slide API Mui in React is triggering listener at start not end

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-transitions, listener, slide

I want to have an object slide to the left side of the screen from the right. This is my code:

```
import rock1 from "src/demos/MyDemo/assets/rock1.png"
import Slide from '@mui/material/Slide';

const Test = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <Slide 
                direction="left" 
                in={true} 
                mountOnEnter unmountOnExit
                timeout={4000}
                easing={{
                    enter: "linear",
                    exit: "linear"
                }}
                addEndListener={()=>alert("Done")}
            >
                <img 
                    height={100}
                    className="Rock" src={rock1}
                    style={{position:"absolute", left: -100, marginBottom:20}}
                />
            </Slide>
        </>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

I want to do some stuff when the transition ends, so I've added a placeholder end listener for now. However, the listener triggers when the transition *starts* and does not trigger again when it ends. Why is it happening at the beginning, not the end, and how can I get it to register correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the react-transition-group [doc](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-prop-addEndListener) that is referenced by MUI on the `Slide` API [page](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/slide/#inheritance), `addEndListener` can be used to add another listener for the transition end and pass a callback.

Live demo for below examples on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8qkn9s?file=src/App.js).

Perhaps try below example for `addEndListener`:

```
  addEndListener={(node, done) =>
    //  node is the element being transitioned
    node.addEventListener(
      //  This event fires at the finish of transition
      "transitionend",
      (e) => {
        //  Do something here
        console.log("Actually done");
        done(e);
      },
      false
    )
  }
```

However, according to the above sources, it seems that another way to achieve the same result here is by adding a callback to the prop `onEntered`:

```
  onEntered={() => console.log('onEntered fired')}
```

Despite the name, `onEntered` is fired when the transition is complete here, while another prop `onExited` runs when the exit transition concludes, if applicable. More details can be found in above source links.

Hope this will help.